# ORACLE : Select Rows Where First, Last or both Characters are Special or Punctuation, excluding Dot '.' if Last

Tags: regex, oracle

I need to retrieve rows from table, in the Column [Client Name].

My request is need to prevent Names that Start or End with a [:space:] or other special Character [:punct:], excluding the dot '.' - at the end of the Name.
The Idea is to pull Names that are Possible inconsistencies.

examples that must appear:

1. 'GEORGE & SON ' - has an extra space at the end.
2. '-GEORGE & SON' - has an extra '-' at the start.
3. '&GEORGE & SON' - has an extra '&' at the start.
4. '-GEORGE & SON S.A.' - has an extra '-' at the start. The Dot '.' at the 
                          end it's not a problem.
5. 'GEORGE & SON..' - has not one, but two dots at the end. That is an 
                      exception for the strings that ends with more than one 
                      '.'; they are also bad names.

examples that must not appear:
    'GEORGE & SON.' - Only has an extra '.', at the end.

I'm using the expression:
REGEXP_LIKE(col, '(^[[:punct:]]|[[:punct:]]$)|(^[[:space:]]|[[:space:]]$)')
But in spite of retrieving Names that start or end with space or special characters, is also pulling the ones that have a dot '.' on last character.

Can anybody help me, please?

Leopoldo Fernandes
Lisbon - Portugal

Comment: Bem vindo ao [pt.so]! Por favor clique em **[edit]** e traduza a pergunta para português.

Comment: Peço imensa desculpa. Coloquei esta questão no Stackoverflow americano e acabei por obter resposta satisfatória. Agradeço o comentário hkhotsubo.

Comment: Tudo bem, vc ainda pode **[edit]** a pergunta e deixá-la em português, se quiser. Ou apagá-la, se achar que não é mais necessária. :-)